# Using while loop,I am getting the input of first 2 strings and then passing the next two strings in function.I am getting index error

Tags: python

I have 5 input strings in my file.txt.I want to get the input of first 2 strings and pass in function and then the next two strings.I am using while loop.But I am getting index error
This is `file.txt`

```
ABCD    
EFGHJ
```

I have tried understanding

```
def lc(s1,s2):
    with open('file.txt.txt', 'r') as f:
        ans = f.read().splitlines()
        i = 0
        while(i<len(ans)):
            lcs(ans[i],ans[i+1]) #getting index error:list index out of range
            i = i+1
```

Comment: What are you expecting from `ans[i+1]` on the last iteration of your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `ans[i + 1]`. When you get to the end of `ans`, doing `ans[i + 1]` will give an index which is not in the range of the array, that is, you're trying to access an element outside of the array. The element following the last one, in this case.

Just change `while(i<len(ans)):` to `while(i<len(ans) - 1):` so that you end the loop one element before the last one, and `ans[i + 1]` access the last element.

**A remark**, what you're doing will give you a sequence of overlapping lines, that is, line 1 and line 2, line 2 and line 3... which doesn't correspond to your question. For that, you must do `i = i + 2;` and `while(i<len(ans) - 2):` instead.

Remember that an array of size `i` has elements at indexes going from `0` to `i - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to read the `i+1`'th element of `ans`, while `i < len(ans)`. So if the length of the array is 3, `i` can take values in `(0, 1, 2)`. Calling `ans[3]` (when `i = 2`) will give you the index error, since you're trying to get the fourth element of an array of size 3.

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with your code:

1. your while statement compares i with len(ans) but then you call ans[i+1] which will trigger this index error when i = len(ans) -1. Don't forget that indices start at 0 and finish at len -1.
2. if you need to pass the lines 2 by 2, you clearly have a logic error here as the first call will pass line 0 and line 1, the second line 1 and 2, etc. so they will overlap

instead of while, I would consider to iterate over a range as follow:

```
    for i in range(0, len(ans) -2, 2):
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking for `len(ans)` in `while` loop, but using `i+1` for indexing afterwards, so for last iteration index it will get out of index for `i+1`.

change the while condition:

```
while(i<len(ans)-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is not too clear, but if I understand correctly, what happens is when the code reaches the last line of the file the while loop tries to grab the next line with the `ans[i+1]`. Since the line doesn't exist it raises an exception.